# XML comment on x has cref attribute that could not be resolved (property and type mix-up)

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, xml-documentation

The following XML comment gives a compile time warning:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides data for the <see cref="TextDraw.Click"/> event.
/// </summary>
public class TextDrawEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    //...

    public TextDraw TextDraw { get; private set; }
}
```

I want TextDraw.Click to refer to the event inside the TextDraw class, but it is picking up TextDraw as the property of this TextDrawEventArgs type.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the full path of the class instead of just `TextDraw`, something like `Namespace.TextDraw.Click`

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add that if your `cref` target contains a generic parameter, you can enclose that in {} brackets in order to resolve.

```
<see cref="Namespace.GenericClass{T}.Method" />
```